# Как спарсить текст со следующего элемента?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

У меня есть вот такой код сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это дни в текущем месяце (Все "tr"), а тот, что "table-success" - текущий день.
На данный момент, я получаю текст оттуда, но как мне сделать так, чтобы программа парсила текст со следующего элемента от "table-success"? Каждые сутки "table-success" опускается вниз и начинается заново, мне нужно всегда парсить текст с элемента, который внизу него, т.е +1.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL), 'lxml')
get_text = soup.find("tr", class_="table-success").find_all("td")
```

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ. Проверьте, возможно будет для Вас актуально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
today_tag = soup.find("tr", class_="table-success")
tomorrow_tag = today_tag.find_next("tr")
```

> В догонку один совет. **НЕ** делайте вот так `tomorrow_tag = soup.find("tr", class_="table-success").find_next("tr")` это впринципе плохая практика. Поскольку если `find` вернет `None` то python выдаст исключение, так как у `None` нет метода `find_next`

#### UPD

***Но есть нюанс...**

Если `"table-success"` будет последней записью таблицы, то `tomorrow_tag` в вышеприведенном примере будет `None`

Поэтому, если такая ситуация возможна, то предлагаю следующее решение:*

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

content = b"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-success">
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = Soup(content, 'html.parser')

records = soup.find_all('tr')
(idx, _), *_ = filter(lambda x: x[1].get('class') == ['table-success'], enumerate(records, start=1))
tomorrow_tag = records[-(len(records) - idx)]

# В случае если элемент класса table-success окажется последним, 
# в переменной tomorrow_tag окажется тэг первой записи таблицы

print(tomorrow_tag)
# <tr>
# <td>1</td>
# </tr>
```

> ***К сведению:***
> В данном примере отсутствует обработка случая, если элемент класса `table-success` вовсе отсутствует в таблице.

#### UUPD:

```py
tomorrow_taq = today_tag.find_next_sibling() or today_tag.find_previous_siblings()[-1] if (
    today_tag := soup.find('tr', class_='table-success')
) else None
```

> ***К сведению:***
> В данном примере, если элемент класса `table-success` отсутствует в таблице `tomorrow_taq` будет иметь значение `None`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. ;)
Тоже стало интересно сначала, что будет, если table-success будет последним.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю сколь это костыльно(пользуюсь bs4 ровно 10 минут), но получил такой код:

**Python:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://localhost/'), 'html')
get_text = [i for i in soup.find("tr", class_="day").parent if i != '\n']
x = get_text[get_text.index(soup.find("tr", class_="day"))+1]
print(x)
```

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>1</tr>
    <tr class="day">2</tr>
    <tr>3</tr>
</tbody>
```

Чтобы проверить работоспособность этого кода, разверните сервер через python.

**Шаги:**

1. Сохраните html в index.html
2. Сохраните python в любой файл расширения .py
3. Откройте cmd и перейдите в папку с index.html
4. Пропишите строку в cmd `python -m http.server 80`
5. Запустите python скрипт

Если вывод python даёт `<tr>3</tr>`, то всё верно работает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.)